# Screen scraping in LXML with python-- extract specific data

Tags: python, screen-scraping, screen, lxml, web-scraping

I've been trying to write a program for the last several hours that does what I thought would be an incredibly simple task:

1. Program asks for user input (let's say the type 'happiness')
2. Program queries the website thinkexist using this format ("http://thinkexist.com/search/searchQuotation.asp?search=*USERINPUT*")
3. Program returns first quote from the website.

I've tried using Xpath with lxml, but have no experience and every single construction comes back with a blank array.

The actual meat of the quote appears to be contained in the class "sqq."

If I navigate the site via Firebug, click the DOM tab, it appears the quote is in a textNode attribute "wholeText" or "textContent"-- but I don't know how to use that knowledge programatically.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's not necessary for you to implement this via XPath, you may use [BeautifilSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html) library like this (let `myXml` variable contain the page HTML source):

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(myXml)
for a in soup.findAll(a,{'class' : 'sqq'}):
  # this is your quote
  print a.contents
```

Anyway, read the BS documentation, it may be very useful for some scraping needs that don't require the power of XPath.

Comment: Glorious!  Just for other people who require assistance: 

The for line should be written: for a in soup.findAll('a',{'class' : 'sqq'}, limit = 1)

Comment: Problem: How do I convert the list into a string without the strange <b> tags and "[u']" notation?  For example, your program on a search for dogs yields this:  [u'Fortunately, for us the problem had been solved a long time ago by Inuit hunters. They figured out their ', <b style="color:#186F79">dogs</b>, u' could smell the seal holes under the snow.']

Comment: What you call "[u']" notation is just Unicode object which is wider than string. If you want to scrape some non-ASCI symbols correctly, you should use Unicode objects. In other way, if you're sure easy string is enough for you, conversion from Unicode object to string is done just like that: str(u'Hello, I am Unicode'). But be careful! If you try to convert Unicode object containing some, let's say, chinese symbols, you'll get an error.

Comment: The answer to your first question is rather simple: you may always write a little bit of your own code. BuautifulSoup.Tag.countents returns you a list of contents, stored in current tag. If you want just take plain text, you may use something like this peace of code: def raw_text(s):
    if isinstance(s, str): return unicode(s);
    if isinstance(s, unicode): return s;
    if isinstance(s, list): return ''.join([raw_text(si) for si in s]);
    if isinstance(s, BeautifulSoup): return raw_text(s.contents);
    if isinstance(s, Tag): return raw_text(s.contents);
    return s.__unicode__()

Answer (score 6):

```
import lxml.html
import urllib

site = 'http://thinkexist.com/search/searchquotation.asp'

userInput = raw_input('Search for: ').strip()
url = site + '?' + urllib.urlencode({'search':userInput})

root = lxml.html.parse(url).getroot()
quotes = root.xpath('//a[@class="sqq"]')

print quotes[0].text_content()
```

... and if you enter 'Shakespeare', it returns

```
In real life, unlike in Shakespeare, the sweetness
of the rose depends upon the name it bears.  Things
are not only what they are.  They are, in very important
respects, what they seem to be.
```

Comment: Wow.  This is perfect.  I have been trying for ages using Beautiful Soup, but whenever it returned the content of  the "sqq" class it included a <b> tag, which I could not remove.  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You could open the html source to find out the exact class you are looking for. For example, to grab the first StackOverflow username encountered on the page you could do:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from lxml import html

url = 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4710307'
tree = html.parse(url)
path = '//div[@class="user-details"]/a[@href]'
print tree.findtext(path)
# -> Parseltongue
# OR to print text including the text in children
a = tree.find(path)
print a.text_content()
# -> Parseltongue
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for all your help.  I guess I didn't have my xpath syntax correct.